# Error schema.find() is not a function when execute function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, mongoose

When Im trying to execute a function and using mongoose to find values in collection I get error find() is not a function
I use require on my schema in the top of the component before the function

```
const resModel = require('../Backend/ResourcesModel')
```

```
    const getResources = () => {
        const cookie = document.cookie;
        const token = cookie && cookie.split('=')[1];
        const decode = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(token.split('.')[1], 'base64'));
        const para = {UserId:decode.user_id};
        console.log(para);
        resModel.find(para)
        .select('Food Marble Gold Solfour')
        .then(result => console.log(result))
    }
```

Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ResourcesTemple = new Schema({
    UserId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    Gold: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    Solfour: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    Marble: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    Food: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}, {versionKey: false});
const Resources = mongoose.model('Resources', ResourcesTemple);
module.exports = Resources;
```

Error:
`Uncaught TypeError: e.find is not a function`

Comment: You should probably share the code of your model as well, since the problem might be there

Comment: Ok, anyway I used find() already in this model in another use.

Comment: I think its because the require schema results nothing, when I console log it I get {}
Why thats happening?

Comment: Require schema?

Comment: Yes, this:
const resModel = require('../Backend/ResourcesModel')
the mongoose model.
when I console.log(resModel) it returns {}
I use this schema in api and thats work properly